# Splitting array values in dataframe into new dataframe - python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a variable that is an array of arrays.  I would like to create a new dataframe from this variable.

My current dataframe 'fruits' looks like this...

```
Id  Name    Color    price_trend
1   apple   red      [['1420848000','1.25'],['1440201600','1.35'],['1443830400','1.52']]
2   lemon   yellow   [['1403740800','0.32'],['1422057600','0.25']]
```

What I would like is a new dataframe from the 'price_trend' column that looks like this...

```
Id    date         price
1     1420848000   1.25
1     1440201600   1.35
1     1443830400   1.52
2     1403740800   0.32
2     1422057600   0.25
```

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A groupby+apply should do the trick.

```
def f(group):
    row = group.irow(0)
    ids = [row['Id'] for v in row['price_trend']]
    dates = [v[0] for v in row['price_trend']]
    prices = [v[1] for v in row['price_trend']]
    return DataFrame({'Id':ids, 'date': dates, 'price': prices})

In[7]: df.groupby('Id', group_keys=False).apply(f)
Out[7]:
   Id        date price
0   1  1420848000  1.25
1   1  1440201600  1.35
2   1  1443830400  1.52
0   2  1403740800  0.32
1   2  1422057600  0.25
```

Edit:

To filter out bad data (for instance, a `price_trend` column having value `[['None']]`), one option is to use pandas [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

```
 criterion = df['price_trend'].map(lambda x: len(x) > 0 and all(len(pair) == 2 for pair in x))
 df[criterion].groupby('Id', group_keys=False).apply(f)
```

Comment: Please forgive me if I'm missing something obvious here (still learning), but when I run the code above I get the error 'NameError: global name 'DataFrame' is not defined'. Any advice?

Comment: Ok, so I changed 'return DataFrame' to 'return pd.DataFrame' and now I'm getting the error message "IndexError: list index out of range".  Any advice for this situation?

Comment: @nflove The error may come from the indexing in `f` (`v[0]` or `v[1]`). Your example data's `price_trend` is a list of lists with 2 elements. If that's not true I'd check my `price_trend` data for bad data (lists with a single element) and filter those out.

Comment: thanks for the response, I think you're right.  Some of my rows are empty and filled with the `[['None']]` placeholder.  Any suggestions of how to edit your code above to handle this?

Comment: @nflove I added an edit to show one way to handle that

Comment: Thanks - this is perfect!